# How to see foreign key value when showing a database in a DataGridView 

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, datasource, sqldatasource

I'm building a Windows forms application that connects to a database.

I used the `generate database from model` function in Visual Studio 2010 to create the database in SQL Server.

I have two tables:

**User**

```
Id (auto_increment)
Username 
Password
```

**UserAddress**

```
Id (auto_increment)
User_Id (fk)
Street
City
```

Now I know how to show those tables in two DataGridViews with the following code:

```
 dataGridViewUsers.DataSource = DBManager.Instance.MyModelContainer.UserSet;
 dataGridViewUserAddress.DataSource = DBManager.Instance.MyModelContainer.UserAdressSet;
```

The problem is that in the `dataGridViewUserAddress` the user column (the one that represents the relationship with the `User` table) does not show the foreign key (User_Id) unique value, it just shows `MyModelContainer.User` for every row in the table.

And this is the same for every relationship in the database, how can I see the actual foreign key value?